# grappelli admin show image

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filebrowser, django-grappelli

I have a new project on django, in which im using Grappelli and filebrowser, and I have extended the User to have a UserProfile related to it, my question is, how can I modify my code to be able to show on the UserProfile information of a user the profile picture uploaded, and also show it on the Users list?

This is my code now, I dont see any image on the admin!

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
     model = UserProfile
     verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'
     list_display = ('city', 'tel', 'description', 'image_thumbnail',)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','date_joined',
        'last_login','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline ]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from apps.common.utils.abstract_models import BaseModel
from apps.common.utils.model_utils import unique_slugify
from filebrowser.base import FileObject
from django.conf import settings

class UserProfile(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=200)
    tel = models.CharField(_("Phone Number"), max_length=50, 
    help_text=_("(Area Code) (Your phone number)"))
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, 
        help_text = _("Small description about yourself."))
    photo = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to="profiles/", 
        null=True, blank=True, default="img/default_profile_image.png")

    def image_thumbnail(self):
        if self.photo:
             return u'<img src="%s" width="80" height="80" />' % self.photo.version(ADMIN_THUMBNAIL).url
        return u'<img src="/site_media/%s" width="80" height="80" />' % settings.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE

     image_thumbnail.allow_tags = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.user.first_name or self.user.last_name:
            return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
        else:
            return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got it, first I wanted to show the image chosen on the UserProfile inline section of the user model for the admin and also on the change list of the admin so heres what I

I changed the models.ImageField to sorl ImageField on the model.py of User profile like this

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class UserProfile(BaseModel):
[...]
    photo = ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to="profiles/", 
        null=True, blank=True, default="img/default_profile_image.png")
```

Then on the admin all I had to do was add sorl's AdminImageMixin on the UserProfileInline class, like this:

```
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin

class UserProfileInline(AdminImageMixin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'
```

And that way you get an image on the UserProfile Inline section on the admin for that user, now for the change_list.

For the change list I had to do a small callable function inside the admin.py file on the UserAdmin class, heres what I did, using sorl's get_thumbnail:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def image_thumbnail(self, obj):
        im = get_thumbnail(obj.get_profile().photo, '80x80', quality=99)
        return u"<img src='/site_media/%s' />" % im
    image_thumbnail.allow_tags = True

    list_display = ('image_thumbnail', 'username','email','first_name','last_name','date_joined',
    'last_login','is_staff', 'is_active',)
```

And now I have a change list image of the user profile and also on the UserProfile Inline section.

Hope this works for everyone out there... and thanks @pastylegs for your previous answer!

Comment: for your first case i.e displaying image in your inline how can we increase the size of thumbnail that appears? comments awaited.. !

Comment: @vijayshanker you can see that on this answer, the last code sample specifically on line 6, theres a string === '80x80' you can change the thumbnail size specifying another dimensions like 90x90 or 60x40

Answer (score 1):

`list_display` needs to be a callable:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

so you can do:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):

    def image_thumbnail(self, obj):
        return obj.image_thumbnail()
    image_thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'

    model = UserProfile
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'
    list_display = ('city', 'tel', 'description', 'image_thumbnail',)
```